# Can someone explain this recycler view adapter for me, the class header and such

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Im trying to create an app with a recyclerview, and I am trying to figure out the following code from an android example. Like what is the onClick value they are putting in the first class, and what is the lambda expression for and what does it do? I notice a similar lambda is in the class below it as well. If anyone can please explain the code. Thank you.

```
class FlowersAdapter(private val onClick: (Flower) -> Unit) :
ListAdapter<Flower, FlowersAdapter.FlowerViewHolder>(FlowerDiffCallback) {

/* ViewHolder for Flower, takes in the inflated view and the onClick behavior. */
class FlowerViewHolder(itemView: View, val onClick: (Flower) -> Unit) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    private val flowerTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.flower_text)
    private val flowerImageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.flower_image)
    private var currentFlower: Flower? = null

    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            currentFlower?.let {
                onClick(it)
            }
        }
    }

    /* Bind flower name and image. */
    fun bind(flower: Flower) {
        currentFlower = flower

        flowerTextView.text = flower.name
        if (flower.image != null) {
            flowerImageView.setImageResource(flower.image)
        } else {
            flowerImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.rose)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onClick` parameter has a type of `(Flower) -> Unit`. That represents a function, which takes a single `Flower` parameter (in the parentheses) and returns `Unit` (i.e. "doesn't return anything").

That means that `onClick` is a function, and you can call it like `onClick(someFlower)`, which is what's happening in that click listener set up in the `init` block. The naming might make it a little confusing, but it's basically this:

- pass in some handler function
- set up a click listener on `itemView`
- when `itemView` is clicked, call the handler function, passing `currentFlower`

so it's just a way for you to provide some behaviour to handle a flower being clicked. You still need the click listener - that's a thing that operates on a `View` and handles click interactions. But inside that listener, you can do what you like when the click is detected, and in this case it's running some externally provided function